# Angularjs with bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

i am using plain angularjs with bootstrap.
i am trying to create page where user lands after login.

so as a deafult route **"/"** the user lands to landing.html

landing.html contains

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#/landing">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#/tags">Tags</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#/help">Help</a></li>
</ul>
```

my problem is that i have nav with Homes tags and  help . on click the selected button background should change. currently its only there form Home `(#/landing)`. also i have problem using this with ng-swipe

any help would be appreciated.

Controller

```
app.controller('indexCtrl', function($scope,$http,$rootScope){

     $('#myModal').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
    });

     $(".nav a").on("click", function(){
   $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});

});
```

Comment: Have you looked into [Angular directives for Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)?

Comment: have you looked at angular-ui http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: the probelm is this app is alreadywritten. i have to write it as a POC.

Comment: and cannot add or change any css js files.

Comment: jQuery functionality doesn't trigger the angular digest cycle, so your changes may not be reflected because of that. Try using $timeout with a delay of 0 or $scope.$apply()

Comment: @ruedamanuel is correct in that jQuery is outside the context of AngularJS.  It's really a mess to try and do both together, but if you just want a quick down and dirty option, you can try the jQuery Passthrough from UI Utils: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/jq

Answer (score 0):

my solution is

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
  <li role="presentation" ng-class="{ active: makeActive('/')}"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" ng-class="{ active: makeActive('/maps')}"><a href="#/maps">Maps</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" ng-class="{ active: makeActive('/help')}"><a href="#/help">Help</a></li>
</ul>
```

and in the controller

```
  $scope.makeActive = function (viewLocation) { 
        return viewLocation === $location.path();
    };
```

This seems to work but how can i add swipe gestures to it.